# HTML5 Video won't loop in Chrome in Linux

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

I have an intranet site displaying and looping a video among other things. Code as follows

```
<video class="embed-responsive-item lobby_video_player" autoplay loop controls 
       src="{{ movie }}"
       type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Upon startup the machine starts Chrome with the address and goes fullscreen, however after it's finished playing the video once it won't loop. The video plays smoothly that 1 time.

It works as expected (loop) on

- Windows 7 + Firefox (different machine)
- Windows 7 + Chrome (different machine)
- Uhbuntu 14.04 + Firefox (same machine)

but not on

- Ubuntu 14.04 + Chrome

The video itself is 650 MB, 1280*720, about 12 Mins. I guess the size is a major factor, since I tried with an extremely short video (5 secs), and the looping was fine.

The machine in question is a minipc, Intel Celeron 1037U 1,8 Ghz, 8GB RAM